# Safe area screen size before and after device has rotated (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to apply different constraints (size, position, color, etc.) to a UIView (of a container view) when the user switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

For some reason, the initial screen height is not the Safe Area height - after rotating the screen it seems to be ok.  What am I doing wrong???

"h = 667.0, w = 375.0"
portrait

"h = 343.0, w = 667.0"
landscape

"h = 603.0, w = 375.0"
portrait

"h = 343.0, w = 667.0"
landscape

"h = 603.0, w = 375.0"
portrait

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { (context) in
        self.setVC1Constraints()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    addChildVC1()
}

func addChildVC1() {
    addChild(childVC1)
    view.addSubview(childVC1.view)
    setVC1Constraints()
}


func setVC1Constraints() {
    let orientation = getScreenOrientation()
    
    let screenHeight = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.height
    let screenWidth = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.width

    print("h = \(screenHeight), w = \(screenWidth)")
    
    childVC1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    childVC1.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    childVC1.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    
    if orientation == Orientations.Portrait || orientation == Orientations.PortraitUpsideDown {
        print("portrait")        }
        
    else if orientation == Orientations.LandscapeRight || orientation == Orientations.LandscapeLeft {
        print("landscape")        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, as you can see the gap is represented by the navigation bar height and quoting Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide):

**safeAreaLayoutGuide**

> The layout guide representing the portion of your view that is unobscured by bars and other content.

> When the view is visible onscreen, this guide reflects the portion of the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestor views.

Comment: I understand that - but why is it giving me the height of the entire screen rather than just the Safe Area on the first pass?  (notice h = 667.0 initially, then h = 603.0 afterwards)

Comment: @Greg According to the docs, if the view is not currently installed in a view hierarchy, or is not yet visible onscreen, the layout guide edges are equal to the edges of the view. So this seems to be your case.

Comment: Any idea how to get it to give me what I need on the first pass?

Comment: You can get the right value in the viewDidLayoutSubviews function. But in this case I suggest to setup your constraints in the viewDidLoad and update their constants with the correct value.

Comment: that did the trick!  Thank you so much!  But is it good programming to  override viewDidLayoutSubviews then call setVC1Constraints from there?  I.e., do all the rest of the stuff that is normally done in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Happy to help! So, as suggested, you still should do all the setup in the viewDidLoad, but you can have a function that only need to update the constraints constants and you can call it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews function when you have the correct layout frame value.